# Is there max limit that a timer can be set for?

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I'm wondering what possible implications could there be if a timer is set for 21 days or large amount of time? I don't see any documentation on a max value or possible negative implications.

Comment: The limit is the maximum value of a `TimeInterval` (which is a Double), so about 10,000 years. But why would you want to use such a large interval for a timer?  Timers are not persisted across app restarts, so if the device is restarted or your app is restarted then the timer is lost

Comment: Timer as in what is provided by Apple has a very short life. About 30 seconds in the background

Comment: the only possible implication (or rather a guarantee) is that such timer will never fire, because no app in ios world can live that long.

Comment: The longest time you can set in the timer apps in iOS and watchOS is 23:59:59 but I have no idea if they use an actual Timer object or some other solution.